# Context Menu to open where left mouse click event occurred

Tags: javascript, contextmenu

I have a wicket application where search results are shown with a context menu icon (Please refer below)

[image: Report with context menu]

I am trying to open context menu exactly on the icon where left mouse click event occurred. however, context menu is displayed below that icon

Here is the code i have tried so far

**HTML**

```
<span href="#" id="contextMenuIcon13">
    <div class="contextCSS">
        <span class="fa fa-bars fa-2x" border="0"></span>
    </div>
</span>
```

**JS code to check mouse click co-ordinates**

```
$(menu).html(buildItems(items));
    // Detect mouse position
    var d = {}, x, y;
    if( self.innerHeight ) {
        d.pageYOffset = self.pageYOffset;
        d.pageXOffset = self.pageXOffset;
        d.innerHeight = self.innerHeight;
        d.innerWidth = self.innerWidth;
    } else if( document.documentElement &&
        document.documentElement.clientHeight ) {
        d.pageYOffset = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        d.pageXOffset = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        d.innerHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        d.innerWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    } else if( document.body ) {
        d.pageYOffset = document.body.scrollTop;
        d.pageXOffset = document.body.scrollLeft;
        d.innerHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
        d.innerWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    }
    (e.pageX) ? x = e.pageX : x = e.clientX + d.scrollLeft;
    (e.pageY) ? y = e.pageY : y = e.clientY + d.scrollTop;

    // Show the menu
    $(document).unbind('click');
    $(menu).css({ top: y, left: x }).fadeIn(o.inSpeed);
```

Above code works, however, menu displays far below. top property seem to be messed up. Any solution? Thanks

Comment: If you're trying to put it directly over the button, could you just swap the button out for it on the click event, and swap back after they've exited the menu?

Comment: Can you please advise it in terms of the code @cheesenthusiast? Thanks